# When using a nested hash maps in dart how to keep track of the series of keys to get to the current nested map?

Tags: json, dart

I am receiving JSON from an api. This JSON controls some dialog for the user. For example

```
{
   "text":"Are you experiecing issues?",
   "true":{
      "text":"Are you using linux?",
      "false":{
         "text":"maybe you should use linux",
         "none":"none"
      }
   }
}
```

To access the final json it the series of keys would be json["true"]["false"]. Is there a way to keep these keys in a variable so I can add or remove these to access different levels?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a function that takes a `List` of keys and performs repeated lookups until it runs out of keys or until it stops finding nested `Map`s:

```dart
Object? nestedLookup(Map<Object, Object?> map, List<Object> keys) {
  Object? value = map;
  int currentKeyIndex = 0;
  while (currentKeyIndex < keys.length && value is Map) {
    value = value[keys[currentKeyIndex++]];
  }
  
  if (value != null && currentKeyIndex < keys.length) {
    // We have more keys than nested Maps.
    throw ArgumentError('Leftover keys: ${keys.sublist(currentKeyIndex)}');
  }
  return value;
}
```

Note that with the above implementation, if you supply too few keys, you'll get back a nested `Map`.  If you supply non-existent keys, you'll get back `null`, and if you supply a key to perform a lookup on something that isn't a `Map`, it will throw an `ArgumentError`.