# How can I programmatically set the value inside a complex Map/List by a given path in Dart?

Tags: dart

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4b9c3d681d4a9e9c03f43ee63343e758) is an example on DartPad.

The example has the commentary but let me explain anyway. Suppose we have a *quite complex* `Map<String, dynamic>` or a `List<dynamic>`, e.g. it might contain an integer inside a map inside a list inside another map inside another list...

I get a path, which I called `targetPath` and is a `List<dynamic>`, defining where the target value is inside this complex data.

I'd like to change the value referred by this `targetPath` but have no idea how to do that.

How can I change a value inside a List/Map given by a path?

Thanks in advance.

## Troubleshooting

I have looked up some solutions on the internet which have not been applicable in my situation but I'd like to put them here and state why they did not work in my case.

### Merging Two Maps

[Combine/merge multiple maps into 1 map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200560/combine-merge-multiple-maps-into-1-map)

I have come across this while looking for it but my case has `targetPath` which is not applicable to this situation. The question has many answers but none of it covers my case.

---

## Environment

- Dart 2.15.1
- Flutter 2.8.1 (if relevant)

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215996/ ?  The code there does a lookup, but it shouldn't be much work to adapt it that code to set an argument instead and to handle nested `List`s.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found a package called [deeply](https://pub.dev/packages/deeply), which addresses the same issue I have at hand.

All the examples adress `Map`s though. However, I took a quick look at the [implementation](https://github.com/marioreggiori/deeply.dart/blob/main/lib/deeply.dart), which seems to be friendly with `List` type *at the first glance*.