# Access Map Through List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have fetch my data from RTDB and store it in variable `locationCountData`. The data for my locationCountData is a nested map of `location_id` and based on the data I created list of the keys. I wanted to access each of the data / keys in the map using for loop and check whether there's a `count` property on it.

Here's my data:

```
location-id-a:{
  location-id-b{
     location-id-c{
       count: 10
       location-id-d:{
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Here's my key list: [location-id-a, location-id-b, location-id-c, location-id-d]

I tried using for loop but it didnt work. It didnt go deep inside the map

```
for (String key in locationList) {
  print('key ${key}');
  if (locationCountData.containsKey(key)) {
    /// What happen if it contains the key
    print("At level $key: $locationCountData");
  } else {
    print('dont exist');
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215996/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if there's a `count` property or not.

Please check below code:

```
void checkForCountProperty(Map data) {
 data.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      if (value.containsKey('count')) {
        print('$key has count property: ${value['count']}');
      } else {
        print('$key does not have count property');
      }
      // Recursively check nested maps
      checkForCountProperty(value);
    }
  });
}
```

and then

```
List<String> keyList = [
    'location-id-a',
    'location-id-b',
    'location-id-c',
    'location-id-d'
  ];

for (String key in keyList) {
if (data.containsKey(key)) {
  print('$key exists in the data.');
  checkForCountProperty(data[key]);
} else {
   // does not exist in the data.
  print('$key does not exist in the data.');
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have faces this problem. But this is working fine for me uses above code. Thank you for support @naman R.