# Iterate through map using list of ID Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My App have a button that will change the `meeting_type` of an ticket. This ticket is associated with some `location_id`. And some `location_Id` might be a child of other location (tree-level structure).

I manage to get all the Id list, First Id in the list is the deepest child and the last Id is the root parent location id.

now from this List of ID. I want to use a for loop to check one bye one, each level deep. if my Map data have the current key (because the list is an tree-level-structure ID). If not I want to break the for loop and directly assign the key and value to empty.

Here's my current code:

```
tempData:{
location-id-a:{
  location-id-b{
     location-id-c{
       ticket_list: ['ticket_id_a','ticket_id_b','ticket_id_c']
       location-id-d{
       }
     }
  }
}
```

```
  for (int i = locationList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      String key = locationList[i];

      if (i == 0) {
        if (tempData[key].containsKey('temuan_list')) {
          List<String> temuanList = List.from(tempData[key]['temuan_list']);
          if(temuanList.contains(temuanId) == false){
            temuanList.add(temuanId);
          }
          tempData[key]['temuan_list'] = temuanList;
        } else {
          tempData[key]['temuan_list'] = [temuanId];
        }
      } else {
        /// Check if the data exist we dive deeper
        if (tempData.containsKey(key)) {
          tempData = tempData[key];
        } else {
          /// Here's the problem because I can't keep the nested structure and cannot assign the key dynamically depending on the ID remaining length
          tempData[locationList[2]][locationList[1]][locationList[0]] = {};
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior ?

Comment: Your current code won't work. `i >= 0` will break the loop on  its first iteration. Is this a typo?

Comment: Is this different from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78138216/)?